# Microsoft Excel 2013-Categorize Data as 1st 2nd, 3rd

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a huge dataset where I'm trying to determine which line of data is a truck's 1st trip, 2nd trip or 3rd trip.
I'm not sure how to automatically assign 1, 2 or 3.
So below in the table Truck #680 has two times for 10/1/2013 (D3 and D4). I would want to assign 1st to D3, then 2nd to D4.

[Truck Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPcP2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `COUNTIF` function. In cell E1, enter `=COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)`. For your data, this will count the number of times in the dataset that the truck has a recorded time. Drag that formula down for the rest of the data.

How it works:
`C$2:C2` tells it to start counting from cell C2 to the current row. The final `C2` in the formula tells it to search for the truck listed in that row.

Comment: Thank you, Kyle. This totally worked. I was missing the $ in my COUNTIF which just gave me the number of times of the occurrence, not 1st, 2nd, 3rd.  :-)

Comment: Glad to help! Thanks for accepting the answer too, I needed the reputation :D